# How to easily truncate an array with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Linq has a convenient operator method called `Take()` to return a given number of elements in anything that implements `IEnumerable`. Is there anything similar in jQuery for working with arrays?

Or, asked differently: how can I truncate an array in Javascript?

Answer (score 276, accepted):

There is a [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
arr = arr.slice(0, 4);
console.log(arr);
```

Will return the first four elements.

Don't forget to assign it back to your variable if you want to discard the other values.

Note: This is just regular javascript, no need for jquery.

Comment: Wouldnt (0,4) return the first 4 not the first 5?

Comment: That's actually not true. Simon Keep is correct - the .slice() method's second argument is the array position *after* the last element to be returned. array.slice(0, 4) would return elements 0, 1, 2, and 3 - a total of 4 elements. Think of the second argument as the cutoff point, where .slice(0, x) will return all elements from the beginning of the array, up to but *not* including x.

Comment: `end` is NOT included, then @SimonKeep is right, see MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: Remember to assign it back to the variable, its very important as simple as it might seem

Comment: bad way, you create a new array instance, keep in mind memory usage when coding js is not a bad idea.

Comment: It bears mentioning that Array.prototype.slice() will simply stop at the end of the array and return without error if the supplied end index is larger than the length of the array. This is a convenient and usually expected behavior. Messing with the length property of the array object will have give a less desirable behavior, as the answer below has described.

Comment: Good note, @pscl. The answer has been updated to avoid that behavior if it is not desired.

Answer (score 163):

(2 years later...) If you're truly looking to truncate an array, you can also use the `length` attribute:

```
var stooges = ["Moe", "Larry", "Shemp", "Curly", "Joe"];
stooges.length = 3; // now stooges is ["Moe", "Larry", "Shemp"]
```

Note: if you assign a length which is **longer** than current length, undefined array elements are introduced, as shown below.

```
var stooges = ["Moe", "Larry", "Shemp"];
stooges.length = 5;
alert(typeof stooges[4]); // alerts "undefined"
```

EDIT:

As @twhitehead mentioned below, the addition of undefined elements can be avoided by doing this:

```
var stooges = ["Moe", "Larry", "Shemp"];
stooges.length = Math.min(stooges.length, 5); 
alert(stooges.length)// alerts "3"
```

Comment: I was surprised first when I saw this in a code... But it's the best way (if you are truncating from index 0) http://davidwalsh.name/empty-array

Comment: What about garbage collection doing thi way?

Comment: @G.Ghez, no problems there. What concerns do you have?

Comment: @JonathanM Actually, null values are not introduced; the new variables are undefined, as they are declared but not assigned any value.

Comment: Good catch, @Håvard. Updated.

Comment: Amazing! It's worth to say that this method is modifying the same `Array` instead of creating a new `Array`.

Comment: To truncate to a specific length without introducing undefined elements at the end, try `stooges.length = Math.min(stooges.length,5);`

Comment: Resetting the length seems to be way way slower than stooges = [] or stooges = null. See this jsperf https://jsperf.com/array-destroy

Comment: Hi, @hitautodestruct. Your statement may be true. However, the goal with truncating is not to empty the array, or to set it to null. Truncating is about keeping the first indices, while getting rid of the latter indices.

Comment: @JonathanM You're correct. But, if you are truncating from index 0 this is very very slow and has the same effect as emptying the array. Also, slice would be better and more verbose for truncating :-)

Comment: @hitautodestruct, I would agree, but I think the heart of the OP's question was about truncating from somewhere other than index 0. As to slice being better, a definition of better would be required for me to agree.

Comment: @JonathanM Well, for me, `slice` is basically what you would intuitively use for truncating an array, it's faster and more readable. But I guess better is a relative term.

Comment: @G.Ghez **The truncated are garbage-collected.** The `.length` setter actually deletes (“dereferences”) the properties. Check it out: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(array)`.

Comment: With `"use strict"`, I get `TypeError: setting getter-only property "length"`.

Answer (score 27):

If you're asking how to truncate (modify an array by removing the elements from the end) then use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
var a1 = [2,4,6,8];
var a2 = a1.splice(-2,2); // a1=[2,4], a2=[6,8]
```

If you're asking how to retrieve a subset of an array without modifying the original, then use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

```
var a1 = [2,4,6,8];
var a2 = a1.slice(-2); // a1=[2,4,6,8], a2=[6,8]
```

Just remember splice modifies, slice accesses. Negative numbers as first arg indicate index from the end of the array.

Answer (score 17):

Set .length property to a lower value.

Official documentation:
[Array.prototype.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

Comment: to kill all elements in the array, setting length to zero is easiest.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to both get the elements as well as remove them from the array, use [splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp).

If you want to keep the elements in the array, use [slice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to selectively pull elements out of an array, you can use the [jQuery.grep](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.grep#arraycallbackinvert) method.

(from the jQuery docs)

```
var arr = [ 1, 9, 3, 8, 6, 1, 5, 9, 4, 7, 3, 8, 6, 9, 1 ];

$("div").text(arr.join(", "));

arr = jQuery.grep(arr, function(n, i){
  return (n != 5 && i > 4);
});

$("p").text(arr.join(", "));

arr = jQuery.grep(arr, function (a) { return a != 9; });
$("span").text(arr.join(", "));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a take(3), I'm going to assume the array is originally being defined as the argument 3

```
const result = new Array(3) 
// result = [undefined , undefined , undefined]
```

If you iterator only returns 2 values, or the values are filtered after the take(3) command and 1 of your values is removed the array would look like

```
//result = [1 , 1 , undefined]
```

so to truncate the array of empty elements you can use

```
 result.filter((value) => value !== undefined);
```