# Angular - How do I loop table rows?

Tags: html, angular6

I want to loop my table for a constant 10 rows. If my array has only 5 items , it has to have the remaining 5 rows with empty value.

This is how I output my table:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
     <td>{{item.id}}</td>
     <td>{{item.name}}</td>
     <td>{{item.desc}}</td>
</tr>
```

How do I make sure it always has 10 rows?
Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those things where it's perhaps worth not overthinking it - if you want to enforce a number of rows, and it's a low number such as 10, then you can just code the table explicitly like that:

```
<tr>
    <td>{{items[0].id}}</td>
    <td>{{items[0].name}}</td>
    <td>{{items[0].desc}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{items[1].id}}</td>
    <td>{{items[1].name}}</td>
    <td>{{items[1].desc}}</td>
 </tr>
...
```

Angular should handle the empty values gracefully.

A better solution however, perhaps if you want to change the number dynamically etc, is you can simply fill your array with null values in your model.

You can use [Array.fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) for this.

Like so:

```
if(array.length < 10){
    array = array.fill(null,array.length, 10);
}
```

Likewise you can easily [truncate an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953071/how-to-easily-truncate-an-array-with-javascript) for results that are over 10.

Answer (score 1):

you need to first check the array size in typescript file for example

```
 array:any=[];
DataAssign(){
       array=//your data;
      now check the array size
     if(array.length<=5){   
   now make object fo array and push ex
   for(int i=0; i<=(array.length-10); i++)
   {
    let obj={id:"",name:"",desc:""};
     array.push(obj);
    }
    }
     }
```

Comment: thanks , your solution works also , but Chris's has a simple solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

```
<tr *ngFor="let index of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]">
 <td>{{items[index]?.id}}</td>
 <td>{{items[index]?.name}}</td>
 <td>{{items[index]?.desc}}</td>
</tr>
```

You can use Array.fill for instead of [0,1,2,3,...].